# How To Allow Access to Certain File Types but Deny All Others

Tags: .htaccess

While I'm confident this has been asked and answered somewhere, my Google and SO searches have not helped me solve what seems like a fairly easy problem.

The goal:
Deny access to ALL file types **except** images.

Current .htaccess file:

```
<Files *.*>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
</Files> 
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg|JPG|PNG|GIF|JPEG)$">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

I still cannot (via the browser) access any image files, with a "403 Forbidden" error.

Questions:
1. How do I make this work properly without rewrite rules?
2. Can I combine `Files` and `FilesMatch` rules like this?
3. Are the `FilesMatch` rules case sensitive?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this via `mod_rewrite` rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule !\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ - [NC,F]
```

Using `FilesMatch` you could do this:

```
Order deny,allow

# first deny all files
<Files *>
deny from all
</Files>

# then allow all image files
<FilesMatch "(?i)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$">
  allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```